# Java Serial programming

Tags: java, serial-port

So I am trying to read data of a serial device connected to a com port.
Now i figured out the reading part but what I wanted to know is how can I identify whether the device connected is my device or just some else like a mouse or keyboard.
For reference I am using the jssc

thanks a bunch!

This bit  below uses Jssc to read rfid tags from my rfid reader

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
    try {
        serialPort.openPort();//Open serial port
        byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(12);
        serialPort.closePort();//Close serial port
    }
    catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you already have. Being very specific about the question help in getting answers.

Comment: I think you should set other port parameters (baudrate, databits, stopbits, parity, ...) before opening it, this is general guidline, so receiver and transmiter are using same link parameters.

Comment: Oh okay,thanks ! but that doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly your intention, but you can use AT commands to get devices info, something like

```
serialPort.writeString(String.format("ATI%n"));
```

be sure to wait after you send command before you'll try to read answer from device.